# Setting permissions on SMB

Tags: permissions, router, smb, wlan

My router (Netgear DGN-2200-64) has a USB port usable as SMB storage (with the default firmware - I guess it's Linux under the hood). I plugged in an old flash disk (FAT formatted I think) & set it up without access restrictions (it's only accessible from the local network).

I'd like to set permissions on a folder (eg for backups that won't get delete by mistake). In smbclient:

```
smb: \> chmod 750 <foldername>
```

didn't work - I could delete the folder from a different (Windows) computer on the network.

I realised the FAT formatting of the flash disk is probably the problem - but it that the sole problem?

Or would I also need to password protect the SMB share? (Another password for forget, particularly for my parents, so I'm reluctant.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FAT formatting won't allow you to set any permissions. There is no way to change that since FAT can't store that kind of meta-data.

*(Well, actually, from Linux side, you can specify permissions while mounting the FAT device, but the permissions will be the same for all that device and I think you can't change the mount options of your router)*

NTFS manages permissions, but it may be tricky to set them on your router.

I'd format your USB flash disk with something like `ext3`, `ext4` or `xfs` (maybe `ext3` has more chance to be "recognized" by your router), and set permissions as you did with `chmod`.

Whatever the Samba permissions are, they can't override a restriction done with `chmod`. Say you set your file `750`, Samba could deny the read access to the group, but it couldn't allow write access to that group.

However, you'd have to know from which user the samba process of your router is run in order to set the correct user and group to your directory.
(if you can't SSH, just try to create a dummy file on your USB disk from SMB, then see the owner and group IDs).

You'd also have to ensure the samba can manage user sessions (else, each user of your house is actually seen as the same user from samba point of view. In that case, setting permission is quite useless...). Unfortunately, for that point, you'd need to see the samba configuration.